# (VBA) Looping through sheet codenames

Tags: vba, indexing

In VBA, I know it's possible to loop through worksheets like so:

```
for i = 1 to 5
msgbox worksheets(i).cells(1,1)
next
```

which pulls the first 5 sheets (in order from left to right) in the workbook. How can I reference the sheet's codenames instead? As in the first worksheet in the workbook might be Sheet10, the second Sheet6, etc...So if I'm trying to loop using sheet#s (codenames), is that possible?

Comment: The answer depends on your final goal. if it is to launch specific VBA methods in the worksheet, there's an answer, but if you want just to iterate on the sheets according to the order of their code-names, there's a different answer. Oh and by the way, names are different than code-names are different than indices. These are totally independent of each other.

Comment: @A.S.H apologies, I edited my question. I'm hoping to iterate through the codenames. For example, for a workbook with 30+ sheets, I'm trying to loop through only codenames 10-15

Comment: Just to make sure, *name* or *codeName*? The former is what you see in the tab bar in Excel. The latter is the name of the corresponding module in the VBA editor.

Comment: codeName. Correct, the name that corresponds to the module displayed in the editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own collection of worksheets that you can index by the code-name. This function does that:

```
Function SheetsByCodeName() As Collection
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set SheetsByCodeName = New Collection
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        SheetsByCodeName.Add sh, sh.CodeName
    Next
End Function
```

and then you can use it for your indexing, like so:

```
dim sheetsByCN as Object: Set sheetsByCN = SheetsByCodeName
dim cn
For each cn in Array("Sheet10","Sheet11","Sheet22","Sheet5","Sheet1")
    debug.print sheetsByCN(cn).Cells(1,1).value
Next
```

Comment: thanks for the response. the reason for creating a collection is codeName's a property and not an object?

Comment: @excelmonkey93 `codeName` is a property, of type string. To index with it, all we need is to create our own collection and use it as a key. The `Worksheets` collection already does the same but with the names, not the codenames, that's why we need to make something similar.

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

The is no indexer on codeName so you have to loop through the sheets yourself.
A very basic example would be something like this:

```
Public Sub FindSheets()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet

    For i = 1 To 5
        Set objSheet = FindSheetByName("Sheet" & i)
        If objSheet Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No sheet with codename Sheet" & i
        Else
            MsgBox objSheet.Name & " has codename " & objSheet.CodeName
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function FindSheetByName(ByVal v_strCodeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim objSheet As Worksheet

    Set FindSheetByName = Nothing

    For Each objSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If objSheet.CodeName = v_strCodeName Then
            Set FindSheetByName = objSheet
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to index sheets by their CodeName.
You can either loop all sheets and check their CodeName, or use a separate method:

```
Sub processSheet(ws As Worksheet)
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(1)
End Sub

Sub process()
    processSheet(Sheet10)
    processSheet(Sheet11)
    processSheet(Sheet12)
End Sub
```

Another alternative might be (not tested):

```
For Each ws In Array(Sheet10, Sheet11, Sheet12)
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(1)
Next
```

Answer (score -2):

If the sheets called Sht1, Sht2, ,, Sht5 
Then

```
for i = 1 to 5
msgbox worksheets("Sht" & i).cells(1,1)
next
```

Comment: i'm looking to iterate through the sheet codenames, not the sheet names.